# Switching layouts in React while maintaining state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design

I have a small React web app written in two different layouts: one for desktop and one for mobile. I'd like to combine the two into one that will switch between the layouts depending on the window size. Ideally, I'd have a switch at the root of the app like this:

```js
const Root = () => {
  return isMobile ? <MobileLayout /> : <DesktopLayout />;
}
```

Most of the components are reused between the two layouts, but there are a few components that rely on state, so switching between the layouts will cause them to lose it. I could refactor the layouts so the stateful components aren't conditionally rendered, but is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: You could store some data on centralized state (like redux for example)

Comment: What about tablet? What about horizontal and vertial views on mobiles and tablets? What about resizing your desktop browswer? Have a look the material-ui library. They use the grid system with the ability to support hiding, showing and repositioning components based on media queries.https://material-ui.com/. Like Max said, I'd also consider moving your state to a central source, like redux or use the React Context api.

Comment: If you have less amount of common data, it prefer to use Context, Redux integration might be difficult at start

Answer (score 3):

I think most easiest way is to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) in React. All state that should be preserved during layout switches should be placed in `Root` component and passed as props to `<MobileLayout />` and to `<DesktopLayout />`. In case of state update required from `<MobileLayout />` or `<DesktopLayout />`, you can use callbacks.

For example

```
const Root = () => {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState({})
  return isMobile ? <MobileLayout someState={someState} setSomeState={setSomeState}/> : <DesktopLayout someState={someState} setSomeState={setSomeState}/>;
}
```

Inside `<MobileLayout />` and `<DesktopLayout />` you can pass stets received from `Root` down to child components the same way, using props.